# Reset a single record in My.Settings VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a lot of records in my Settings but I don't want to use

```
My.Settings.Reset()
```

Because it will reset everything.
I just want to reset like 1-3 record only, is it possible?

Comment: Assuming you know the default value, you can just manually set the 1-3 that you want to reset to that default value, just as you would if you were changing the value.

Comment: I used the settings that I mentioned here to store path directory so there's actually no default value, and if i reset it, i don't want the other records to be reset too, and the other records are for storing login information.

Comment: Settings doent have "records" all of them are always saved or loaded or reset.

Comment: So I cannot reset a specific setting?

Comment: Yes, you set those specific settings to their default value. If the setting contains a path, I assume it is a string and the default would be an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

A little late but try:

```
my.settings.(record name) = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

This example gets the Default value of a setting:

```
My.Settings.PropertyValues("CustLineWidth").Property.DefaultValue
```

or

```
Dim defaultValue = My.Settings.Properties(NameOf(My.Settings.CustLineWidth)).DefaultValue
```